# How to make a nestjs + graphql deployment to now.sh?

Tags: typescript, deployment, nestjs, vercel

**Problem**
Hi devs,

I would like to see if someone can help me how to make a nestjs + graphql deployment to now.sh. 
I already did the build with the following command

```
"build": "nest build",
```

I tried to do the deployment, but when I go to the url `https://animeflv-gql.chrismichael.now.sh/ graphql`

it shows me an error

```
502: BAD_GATEWAY
Code: NO_STATUS_CODE_FROM_FUNCTION
ID: chs1:5ppst-1581278680565-60e10864b74c
```

**now.json**

```
{
  "version": 2,
  "name": "animeflv-gql",
  "builds": [
    {
      "src": "dist/main.js",
      "use": "@now/node"
    }
  ],
  "routes": [
    {
      "src": "/(.*)",
      "dest": "dist/main.js"
    }
  ]
}
```

**app.module.ts**

```js
import { Module } from '@nestjs/common';
import {GraphQLModule} from '@nestjs/graphql'
import { AnimesModule } from './animes/animes.module';


@Module({
  imports: [
    GraphQLModule.forRoot({
      typePaths: ['./**/*.graphql'],
      resolverValidationOptions:{
        requireResolversForResolveType: false
      },
      playground: true,
    }),
    AnimesModule,
  ],
})
export class AppModule {}
```